# How can I do a multidimensional search with JSON in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, performance, search

I am trying to write a basic, experimental search system using JavaScript and JSON, with the searchable data contained in the JSON file. Multiple 'posts' are listed in the file, and each post has an array of 'tags'. My intent is to search through each posts tags, and retrieve only the posts that have tags matching a query, such as "funny cat video" (the posts would have to have all three tags, "funny", "cat", and "video", to be returned).

My particular concern is performance. I am sure that this technique will be inefficient, as there are approximately 2000 posts, and each one has from 5 to 50 tags, but it has to be done with JavaScript. I am already referencing from this website on how to maximise performance, though I could do with some extra help.

Here is my code so far for storing the data:

```
{
    "index": {
        "count": "2",
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "date": "2014-11-21 17:16:39 GMT",
                "url": "http://url/",
                "image": "http://big_image/",
                "thumbnail": "http://little_image/",
                "tags": ["funny", "cat", "picture", "falling", "chair", "window sill", "funny"]
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "date": "2014-11-20 17:57:32 GMT",
                "url": "http://url1/",
                "image": "http://big_image1/",
                "thumbnail": "http://little_image1/",
                "tags": ["funny", "cat", "picture", "jumping", "water", "bath", "funny"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
var query = "funny cat bath".split(" ");
var data = JSON.parse("THE JSON GOES HERE");
var count = data.index.count;
var index = data.index.posts;
for (var i = 0, indexLength = index.length; i < indexLength; i++) {
    tags = index[i].tags;
    for (var q = 0, queryLength = query.length; q < queryLength; q++) {
        if(tags.indexOf(query[q]) !== false) {
            console.log(index[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get it to return only the posts that have all three tags, and it returns all posts with any of the tags supplied. Not only that, but it returns duplicates.

Does anybody have a better solution? I'm stuck.

Comment: I want to reiterate, this has to be JavaScript. I'd have been much happier writing this in something server-side, using a database, but that is not an option.

Comment: Have you considered using [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) instead? It's client-side but, as the name suggests, indexed for performance.

Comment: That's actually pretty interesting, Jordan, but I need the page to be able to load on any computer and carry out the same operation, hence loading a file. Unless I'm missing something, IndexedDB requires the data to be stored in the browser?

Comment: Either way you have to store the data in the browser. In one case you're putting the data into a plain old JavaScript object; in another case you're putting the data into an IndexedDB database.

Comment: I'm going to learn more about that, but I'm going to use the accepted answer for now, until I've figured out how to use an IndexedDB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a flag and only "write" out the match when they are all found, you are writing it out when one is found. Plus indexOf returns -1, not false. Basic idea below:

```js
var data = {
    "index": {
        "count": "2",
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "date": "2014-11-21 17:16:39 GMT",
                "url": "http://url/",
                "image": "http://big_image/",
                "thumbnail": "http://little_image/",
                "tags": ["funny", "cat", "picture", "falling", "chair", "window sill", "funny"]
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "date": "2014-11-20 17:57:32 GMT",
                "url": "http://url1/",
                "image": "http://big_image1/",
                "thumbnail": "http://little_image1/",
                "tags": ["funny", "cat", "picture", "jumping", "water", "bath", "funny"]
            }
        ]
    }
};


var query = "funny cat bath".split(" ");
var filteredSet = [];  //where the matched objects will reside
var posts = data.index.posts;  //get the posts
for (var i=0; i<posts.length;i++) {  //loop through the posts
    var post = posts[i];  
    var tags = post.tags;  //reference the tags
    var hasMatch = true;  //flag to hold the state if we have a good match - set to true by default
    for (var j=0; j<query.length; j++) {  //loop through the tags the user is looking for
        var index = tags.indexOf(query[j]);  //look for it in the set [Note older IEs needs polyfill see MDN for code]
        if (index===-1) { //indexOf returns -1 if not found
            hasMatch=false;  //set Boolean flag so we do not record item
            break;  //exit loop - no reason to keep checking
        }
    }
    if (hasMatch) { //if we found all the tags
        filteredSet.push(post); // add to the filtered set
    }
}
console.log(filteredSet);  //show the filtered set
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. I can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: I agree, Jordan, which is why I'm going to do more research into IndexedDB as well, and find out what is faster. Anything a bit more optimized would probably be good.